# In Visual Studio, how can I detect all the occurrences in C++ code of the ternary operator c?e1:e2 where e1 and e2 are not of the same type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-analysis, conditional-operator, static-code-analysis

In Visual Studio, how can I detect all the occurrences in C++ code of the ternary operator `c?e1:e2` where `e1` and `e2` are not of the same type?

I am not interested in detecting `c?1:2` while for example I am interested in `c?0:std::string{"Hello world"}`.

Comment: I don't think you can make it stricter than standards-conformant.

Comment: @molbdnilo I would be happy just to find all of them in my code :-) *find* as in *Find in Files* command.

Comment: Since the standard allows unambiguous implicit conversion from one expression's type to the other's, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If your code compiles with visual studio you can use: /Zc:ternary

This option enables the standard conform behaviour, where the types can not be unrelates.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-ternary?view=msvc-160

Comment: Unfortunately, `0` can be unambiguously converted to `std::string` (and will most likely cause a runtime error), so the example will go undetected.

Comment: @gerum It seems to me that `c?0:std::string{"Hello world"}` is fine for my Visual Studio compiler, both with `/Zc:ternary` and with `/Zc:ternary-`.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Amusingly 0 is ambiguously convertible to a `std::string` with undefined results at runtime. Oh joy!

Comment: What's the conversion from `0` to `std::string`? The `CharT*` ctor with `0` acting as `nullptr`?

Comment: @NathanPierson yes, both `0` and `nullptr` are null pointer constants